# how can we use v7widget code in android studio?. how to use v7widget in androidx?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, androidx

> **this is my new project want to insert in this old code **<?xml
>
> version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent">
>
> ```
>      </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
> ```
>
> **showing error on v7 widget while inserting old codes  ** <?xml
>
> version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>
> ```
>     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_margin="5dp">
>  
>         <RelativeLayout
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:padding="8dp">
>  
>             <ImageView
>                 android:id="@+id/imageView"
>                 android:layout_width="120dp"
>                 android:layout_height="90dp"
>                 android:padding="4dp" />
>  
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
>                 android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
>                 android:text="Apple MacBook Air Core i5 5th Gen - (8 GB/128 GB SSD/Mac OS Sierra)"
>                 android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
>                 android:textColor="#000000" />
>  
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textViewShortDesc"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_below="@id/textViewTitle"
>                 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
>                 android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
>                 android:text="13.3 Inch, 256 GB"
>                 android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />
>  
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textViewRating"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_below="@id/textViewShortDesc"
>                 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
>                 android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
>                 android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
>                 android:paddingLeft="15dp"
>                 android:paddingRight="15dp"
>                 android:text="4.7"
>                 android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.Inverse"
>                 android:textStyle="bold" />
>  
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textViewPrice"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_below="@id/textViewRating"
>                 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
>                 android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
>                 android:text="INR 56990"
>                 android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
>                 android:textStyle="bold" />
>  
>         </RelativeLayout>
>  
>     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>   </LinearLayout>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of v7widget tag

used
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView